Asset vs capital
In easy money 3 there is an example given about asset to capital ratio of a bank. I'm confused in two things.
The example: Say a bank has 100\$ in assets and 2$ in capital. If the asset value depreciates 1\$ so it now is worth 99\$ then it loses half it's capital. First, It's assets essentially equivalent to capital. I know assets generally are less liquid but this is still 99/2 = 49.8 ~= 50.
I'm deducing that by "it loses half it's capital" to mean that it has to go buy 1\$ in assets to make of for it's loss so now one has 100\$ assets and 1\$ capital and this gives a ratio of 100. This is very different than 49.8. Yet in both cases the "value" is 101\$.
The example makes it seem that when they lose \$1 in assets they lose 1\$ in capital which is really a loss of 2\$ overall.
2nd, why could it not just sell 1\$ in assets to 1\$ in capital so one has 98$ in assets and 2\$ in capital which gives a 48/2 = 49 ratio.
So basically there is a discrepancy between how assets and capital are treated. (A + x)/(C - x) where x can move freely between assets or capital("buying or selling") can change the ratio tremendously without changing the overall value which is (A + x) + (C - x) = A + C.
I assume then what makes all the difference between the two has to do with liquidity and hence x is not "free". I assume the risk is defaulting and even 1 cent in default then blow everything up? Even if the bank has an infinite amount in assets, if they have 0 capital they cannot function and someone else gets those infinite assets for free?
In my mind it makes zero sense why, say, a bank with 0 capital but say, 100T in assets could be infinitely "leveraged". It would seem to me the real leverage is A/(A + C) but I am assuming assets can capital are essentially the same thing on some level.
What I don't get is why a decrease in assets somehow effects the capital. If I have 10k in the bank and my 100k house depreciates by 10k I don't end up with 0k in the bank and a 90k house(or 100k house). Yes, I've lost 10k but it's a loss overall.
What am I missing?

You wrote "[if it has insufficient capital] it has to go buy 1$ in assets to make up for it's loss ". You know accounting ? Assets are on the left side and capital is on the right side. If the assets lose value so does your capital and you have to GET ADDITIONAL CAPITAL or SELL SOME ASSETS, so that again your assets are in the right proportion to your capital. (Though if your capital is still sufficient you don't have to do anything).

@nbbo2 yes, that is what I said. If your assets drop 1$ then if you buy, using your capital which increase A/C ratio. If you sell assets it decreases assets and increases capital which gives a different ratio but in both cases the overall value (assets + capital) is exactly the same. So why is the ratio even used? What is the point of the ratio when it basically only depends on allocation. The only thing I can find that matters seems to be that banks have a certain requirement to hold a certain ratio which, again, I guess has to do with liquidity.

There are 4 key ratios for banking institutions in global regulation; capital ratio and leverage ratio (LR), which are about capital relative to risky exposures, and liquidity coverage ratio (LCR) and net stable funding ratio (NSFR) which seek to monitor the health of an institution's liquidity status.

Basel has clear definitions for capital of a bank.  There is:

Tier 1 Capital (going concern capital)
Tier 2 Capital (gone concern capital)

Common Tier 1 capital (CET1) is predominantly composed of ordinary share capital (not market cap) plus retained earnings. Certain items subject to criteria get added to CET1 capital to make up the whole of Tier 1 capital, e.g. AT1 bonds.
Suppose you start a bank with \$2 of ordinary share capital. I.e the owners invest \$2 of their own money. Their initial balance sheet will look like:
[Assets: \$2 (cash), Liabilities: \$0, Capital: \$2]
Acting as a bank you extend leverage and create broad money supply (i.e. you create a mortgage asset and deposit funds in your customers accounts as liabilities). Your balance sheet is now:
[Assets: \$102 (cash + mortagages), Liabilities: \$100, Capital: \$2]
If the assets fall by \$1 your capital will fall by half.
[Assets: \$101 (cash + mortgages), Liabilities: \$100, Capital: \$1]
This can be seen in one of two ways, either that the sum of assets and liabilities must equal shareholders funds + retained earnings, or recognising that assets falling by \$1 will be accounted for (at fair value accounting) as a \$1 loss and is passed through to retained earnings, which falls under the definition of Common Tier 1 capital described above.
